# Reading the Time Display Format from Excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, time

I am reading a cell of type Time like this:

```
var daysFrom1900 = Convert.ToDouble(cell.CellValue.Text);
content = DateTime.FromOADate(daysFrom1900).ToString("HH:mm");
```

The data in the cell I am reading is displayed as "09:00 AM" and the content that is being read is a string with value "09:00", of course because I am forcing the format. How can I get the display format from the excel file and apply the same format to the string? Basically I want the content to be "09:00" if this is the display value in the cell and "09:00 AM" if it displays AM/PM in the cell.

Both of them has the same value in the cell, but different displays. Is what I want possible?

stepping in the code Cell.CellValue.Text = 0.375

Comment: Read the *value* of the cell, not the text. Either it's *already* a DateTime or it's a double that can be read with `DateTime.FromOADate()` without any conversion

Comment: If you want the original text, why don't you just use it as is?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I read it as a text cell (cell.CellValue.Text), it is a double. If I don't force any formatting, the result is a complete Date (yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

Comment: .Text is a *string* not a double. Which library are you using anyway? The "raw" Open XML SDK? NPOI ? Epplus? Libraries like EPPlus make working with the `xlsx` format a *lot* easier. You could write eg `worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value` and get the double directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean the value of the text is something like a double value "0.375" for example. I am using using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Comment: can you share some sample about cell.CellValue.Text value?

Answer (score 1):

can you try 'tt'

```
content = DateTime.FromOADate(daysFrom1900).ToString("HH:mm tt"); // should return 09.00 AM
```

[see this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1). it's very helpful for date and time format

> tt AM / PM (e.g. AM or PM)

hope this line helps you.

Comment: I can, but then if the display is "09:00" I am forcing the format "09:00 AM", which I don't want to.

Comment: is it possible to read this display as a string? if it contains AM/PM use "HH:mm tt" else use "HH:mm"

Comment: I couldn't read the display as a string, if there is a way to read it, that would be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string parseExcelHour(string cellInput){

double excelHour = 0;

try{
    excelHour = Double.Parse(cellInput);
}catch { }

int hour = (int) (excelHour * 24);
// with the int cast you get only an integer.
int min = (int) (excelHour * 1440 % 60); 
//mod (%) takes only the remainder and then the cast to int will round the number

return (hour < 10? "0":"") + hour + ":" + (min < 10? "0":"") + min + (hour > 12 ? “Pm”:”am”);
}
```

Comment: This is what exactly was needed in order to convert EXCEL Format to human time:minute format.